# Liferay 6.0.1 Extension environment Setup

Tags: liferay

I am new to liferay , i tried to setup extension environment for liferay6. Based on googly i understand the ext environment is  comes as plugin.

But i can't find any instruction for download and install.

Please help me.

Comment: Before you use the EXT you should think whether you absolutely need to or whether a hook or portlet plugin would be more appropriate!

Comment: Do not write portlets in the EXT environment if you can possibly avoid it. Use the Plugins SDK instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ext is a *kind* of plugin that you develop with the plugin SDK.  The Liferay SDK has a directory for each kind of plugin, including ext.  Once you have set up your SDK, then you have set up what you need to develop ext plugins.

For the SDK as a whole: 
http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.0/development/-/ai/liferay-portal-6-0-developer-guide

For the ext portlet plugin development: http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.0/development/-/ai/ext-plugins

Comment: https://web.liferay.com/fr/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Setting+up+the+Extension+Environment